# How to create a grouped bar plot of categorical counts

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

This might be a simple task but I am new to plotting in Python and I struggle to convert logic into code. I'm using the code below but I would like to separate the orange and blue lines (not superimposed). I need to create a horizontal bar plot with the 2 bars separated?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,1,2,2,2],
             'b':[1,1,1,3,2,2,2]})
ax = df['a'].value_counts().plot(kind='barh', color='skyblue', width=.75, legend=True, alpha=0.8)
df['b'].value_counts().plot(kind='barh', color='orange', width=.5, alpha=1, legend=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Convert the dataframe to a long form with [`panda.DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), then do one of the following:

  1. Use [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) to reshape and aggregate `size`, and then plot with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)
  2. Plot directly with [`seaborn.countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html)

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,1,2,2,2], 'b':[1,1,1,3,2,2,2]})

# convert to long form
df = df.melt()

# pivot_table and aggregate
df = df.pivot_table(index='value', columns='variable', values='value', aggfunc='size')

# plot
df.plot(kind='barh', figsize=(4, 3))
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

### `seaborn.countplot`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,1,2,2,2], 'b':[1,1,1,3,2,2,2]})

plt.figure(figsize=(4, 3))
ax = sns.countplot(data=df.melt(), y='value', hue='variable')
sns.move_legend(ax, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df['a'].value_counts().to_frame('a').join(df['b'].value_counts().to_frame('b')).plot(kind='barh')
```

[image]